# RedHat ntp offset becomes bigger over time

Tags: redhat, ntp

I have a strange issue with a server. It is configured to use 2 servers, just like all the other server (the config is the same for a couple of server and they are all working except this one) and it had a huge offset (over 1000s), but every 1h20min it corrects itself and it's back on time for a couple of minutes. So I already did the following:

1. Stopped ntpd daemon
2. Issued the following command:

   ```
   ntpdate -b xxx.xxx.xxx.Xxx
   ```
3. started the ntpd daemon again

But with no result.

My `ntp.conf` file looks like this:

```
listen-on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx accept
server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx burst iburst minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
restrict xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
driftfile /var/lib/ntp.drift
logfile /var/lib/ntpd.log
server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx burst iburst minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
restrict xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
driftfile /var/lib/ntp.drift
logfile /var/lib/ntpd.lo
```

Any advice on what steps to take next? Or a way to fix this?

Best regards

**Update**
The `ntpq -p -crv`

```
[root@xxxxxxxx ~]# ntpq -p -crv
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  3 u   10   16  377    1.992  410.988  10.517
*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  2 u    6   16  377    2.758  420.365  12.230
status=0614 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, event_peer/strat_chg,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p1@1.2158-o Fri Aug 24 16:13:49 UTC 2012 (3)",
processor="i686", system="Linux/2.6.22.9-61.NS5", leap=00, stratum=3,
precision=-21, rootdelay=8.343, rootdisp=457.558,
refid=xxxxxxxxxxxx,
reftime=d7d674da.8041b0f8  Wed, Oct  1 2014 14:40:58.501,
clock=d7d67500.7904168c  Wed, Oct  1 2014 14:41:36.472, peer=59935,
tc=4, mintc=3, offset=223.125, frequency=0.000, sys_jitter=19.824,
clk_jitter=123.945, clk_wander=0.000
```

Comment: I would add a third (and preferably a fourth) server so that ntpd has the ability to detect if one is not keeping good time and delete the /var/lib/ntp.drift file.  Restart ntpd.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the driftfile after it's been re-created.  Also, take a look at the debug.html doc file for ntp.  You'll need to install the ntp-doc package, in which case it will be in /usr/share/doc/ntp-$version/html.  The Debug file has a good discussion on "Verifying Correct Operation" where it talks about frequency errors.  NTP can handle 500PPM, or 43 seconds per day.  You may have a bigger drift -- it mentions tickadj to adjust your kernel frequency.  Be careful with this, it could be dangerous.

Comment: `burst iburst minpoll4 maxpoll 4` is "overkill." Do you understand what all those options mean? Do you really think polling every 16 seconds is a good idea? Is that your entire ntp config? No restrictions at all?

Comment: Two servers is the absolute worst number of servers to use. *A man with one watch knows what time it is,  man with two watches is never sure.* Can you paste the out put of `ntpq -p -crv` after ntpd has been up for a little bit?

Comment: @dfc: added the ntpq -p -crv, yes the polling should be in "overkill" mode as this is a packet-storage and needs correct timestamping.

Comment: **If time was important you would have more or less than two time servers defined. Two is the worst number of servers to use.** Is that your entire ntp.conf? You declare drift file twice? Logging twice with different filenames? Are the upstream servers working properly: Last event was peer stratum change?

Comment: I have defined one server as we don't controll network we are in (it's at customer site). Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had once had a working NTP server. And, of course, I changed something and eventually I noticed that it wasn't working anymore.

I discovered that I had changed my BIOS and had disabled the IOMMU on a machine that was acting as VM hypervisor. And the VM hypervisor was also my NTP server.

I can't believe it was able operate as a hypervisor. So check for IOMMU in kern.log (or dmesg).

Another clue, under time, if timedatectl status works.

Comment: Could you show what the IOMMU log should look like when working right? My log has 8 lines with entries that look like this `DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 12 under DRHD base  0xc5ffc000 IOMMU 6`. The address and last number change. So it seems to be there, yet my NTP is not working...